# SharePoint 2010: Connect to a Remote Service Application - OK Greyed-Out

Tags: 2010, 2013, search, service-application

After I followed the instructions to "[Share service applications across farms in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621100.aspx)", and was finishing Step 4 "[Connect to service applications on remote farms in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704558.aspx)", I'm unable to hit the OK button after pasting in the URL. It is greyed-out.

What is wrong? Can I not have the same Service Application Name? (e.g. Search Service Application).

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, I just had to click on the row in the dialog box that has the words "Search Service Application", then the OK button became un-greyed-out. (Unfortunately I can't show a screen-shot, as I got past this step).